# letter shifting program in python

Tags: python, list, shift, slice

Let's say that I have a list of the alphabet:

```
ALPHABET = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
```

and lets say the shift positions are

0, 2, 19

if the input is a string
string = "xyz"

and I want to shift these 3 characters using the above shift positions of 0,2,19

as in shift `'x'` 0 times to the right, shift `'y'` 2 times to the right, and shift `z` 19 times to the right.

The only thing that comes to mind is something like the `index()` function of lists

I also see another problem. IF I shift `'z'` 19 times to the right I will get an `list index out of range` error. If `'z'` is shifted 19 times to the right I want it to become `'s'` which would be 19 shifts going around the list and starting from the beginning. Same thing with `'y'` if I shift it to the right 2 times I want it to become `'a'` etc....

Any suggestions on what to use?

Comment: I'd suggest using the modulus operator to solve the problem of going out of bounds

Comment: and how would that be done?

Comment: Try to do a little research by your own

Comment: @robertrocha The modulus operator returns the remainder of a division operation; e.g. `19 % 2 = 1 (19 / 2 = 8 remainder 1)`

Comment: Have you heard of a Ring/Circular Buffer? Might give you an idea.

Comment: I know how would I use that in the letter shift?

Comment: no @EugeneK where is that at?

Comment: It's just a list that is connected from head to tail. The technical word for what you're trying to accomplish is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift. As you can see it uses the module operator that Revan is suggesting.

Comment: Homework much, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my way is more basic than TheSoundDefense but it works pretty well when you input three letters like "xyz". (Im guessing you can come up with a check to make sure they did so)

The main tool that i use is the index function which will match an item in the list and will give me the placement number for that item.  Then I take that number and I add it to the numbers you gave.  But then I divide it against the length and take the remainder.  I don't care how many times it divides out to be, i just want the remainder because that tells me where its at in the alphabet.  then I replace the letters and print them out.

```
ALPHABET = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']


print "Please enter three letters"
x = list(raw_input("> ").upper())


length = len(ALPHABET)


first_letter = ALPHABET.index(x[0])
first_letter = (first_letter + 0) % length

x[0] = ALPHABET[first_letter]

second_letter = ALPHABET.index(x[1])
second_letter = (second_letter + 2) % length

x[1] = ALPHABET[second_letter]

third_letter = ALPHABET.index(x[2])
third_letter = (third_letter + 19) % length

x[2] = ALPHABET[third_letter]





print ''.join(x)
```

Comment: I know that the modulos returns the remainder if there is one. What is the purpose of it here?

Comment: Lets take the third letter for example.
If i typed y for the third letter and then we added 19 positions to that we could have a problem because we are at the end of the list.  So we take 25 and add 19 and we get 44.  Then if we do 44 - 26 we get 18.  Instead of subtracting though we should use the modulus.  It gives us the same answer here but if you were trying to shift positions by 128 we would be in trouble with subtraction.  The remainder is much better so that you can use this in multiple scenarios.

Comment: in your `second_letter = (second_letter + 2) % length` that results in 1 when it should be 2

Comment: my calculation using the python shell for `second_letter = (second_letter + 2) % length` is as follows (25 + 2) % 6 gives me a 1

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just realized I was probably answering a totally different question, because my brain doesn't understand the word "shift" properly. So instead of generating new letters, I'm generating an entirely new alphabet. Feel free to point and laugh.

For handling the out-of-range problem, you'll want to use the modulus function `%` to make the number "wrap around". You can use this in conjunction with slicing in order to get your shift.

```
ALPHABET = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

inputstring = "XYZ"

def shift(inputstr, shift1, shift2, shift3):
  new_alphabet = list(ALPHABET)
  shifts = [shift1, shift2, shift3]

  for i in range(0,3):
    inputchar = inputstr[i]
    i1 = new_alphabet.index(inputchar)
    i1_adjust = (i1 + shifts[i]) % len(new_alphabet)

    temp_alphabet = new_alphabet[:i1] + new_alphabet[i1+1:]
    new_alphabet = temp_alphabet[:i1_adjust] + [inputchar] + temp_alphabet[i1_adjust:]
    print new_alphabet

# We call it here.
shift(inputstring,0,2,19)
```

We're basically finding the index of our character and adding our shift amount to it. Then we pull that character out of our alphabet and move along `i1_adjust` number of spaces to the new position. We pull the alphabet apart at that position, insert the character, and glue it back together. The code could probably be more elegant if `shift1, shift2, shift3` was changed to a list of shift positions, but the proof of concept is there.

Comment: how do I use the % to wrap the word

Answer (score 0):

Can i solve this way: Let me know if you don't like this solution in comment, I will remove it. ( instead of down-voting )

```
#!/usr/bin/python

alpha = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I',\
        'J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R',\
        'S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

def shift_right(char, shift_inx):

    dic1 = dict(zip(alpha, range(26)))
    dic2 = dict(zip(range(26), alpha))

    total = len(alpha)

    nxt_inx = dic1[char] + shift_inx

    if nxt_inx <= 25:
        return dic2[nxt_inx]
    else:
        return dic2[nxt_inx % total]

def main():
    for x,y in [('X', 0), ('Y', 2), ('Z', 19)]:
        print '%s => %s => %s' % ( x, y, shift_right(x, y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
X => 0 => X
Y => 2 => A
Z => 19 => S
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/python

alpha = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I',\
        'J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R',\
        'S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

def shift_right(char, shift_inx):

    total = len(alpha)

    nxt_inx = alpha.index(char) + shift_inx

    if nxt_inx <= 25:
        return alpha[nxt_inx]
    else:
        return alpha[nxt_inx % total]

def main():
    for x,y in [('X', 0), ('Y', 2), ('Z', 20)]:
        print '%s => %s => %s' % ( x, y, shift_right(x, y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In this case you don't need to add `if nxt_inx <= 25:`, since the `%` operator does nothing if that's true anyway.